# Rearrange Dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on some survey data and was wondering if i could rearrange the data to make it a lot more usable. The results are classified as 1-5 and I would like the preferred table to count the results by value and group by question.

original table:

```
year | month | customer_id | survey | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5 | q6 ----> q29
-----|-------|-------------|--------|----|----|----|----|----|---
2016 | Oct   | ABC12345678 | 1      | 1  | 2  | 3  | 1  | 2  | 3 
2016 | Oct   | DEF12345678 | 1      | 2  | 1  | 4  | 2  | 1  | 1
2016 | Oct   | GHI12345678 | 1      | 4  | 2  | 1  | 1  | 3  | 2 
2016 | Oct   | JKL12345678 | 1      | 2  | 3  | 2  | 4  | 1  | 3 
2016 | Oct   | MNO12345678 | 1      | 5  | 2  | 3  | 1  | 2  | 3 
2016 | Oct   | PQR12345678 | 1      | 3  | 4  | 4  | 2  | 4  | 4 
2016 | Oct   | STU12345678 | 1      | 1  | 5  | 3  | 1  | 2  | 5 
2016 | Oct   | VWX12345678 | 1      | 2  | 2  | 4  | 2  | 1  | 1
```

Preferred Table:

```
Year | Month | Survey | Question | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  |
-----|-------|--------|----------|----|----|----|----|----|
2016 | Oct   |   1    |   q1     | 80 | 45 | 25 | 63 | 89 |  
2016 | Oct   |   1    |   q2     | 65 | 75 | 35 | 53 | 69 |
```

I can do this with a basic select query but to do it for every question will end up with 29 unions and there must be a quicker way.

Regards,

Neil

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  However, this type of restructuring usually requires a complex query.

Comment: figured as much Gordon, nevermind then :)

Comment: This can be done a lot simpler than 29 unions. You will first need to unpivot this and then do conditional aggregation. for us to truly help it would be great if you could post ddl and sample data.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Ms SQL. Will post a  dataset in a few mins.

Comment: werent sure how to post sample data, just amended the table in the question. How do I get ddl?

Comment: If possible, you should reorganize your original table so that you have one row with year/month/customer/survey/question_num/value. This would let you add questions in the future without having to alter your table structure. And with this structure, your results would be easy to query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would use until someone posts a better solution:

```
    <!-- language: lang-sql -->

use tempdb;
create table #tempsurvey (year int, month varchar(32), customer_id varchar(32), survey int, [q1] int, [q2] int, [q3] int, [q4] int, [q5] int, [q6] int, [q7] int, [q8] int, [q9] int, [q10] int, [q11] int, [q12] int, [q13] int, [q14] int, [q15] int, [q16] int, [q17] int, [q18] int, [q19] int, [q20] int, [q21] int, [q22] int, [q23] int, [q24] int, [q25] int, [q26] int, [q27] int, [q28] int, [q29] int);
insert into #tempsurvey values (2016,'Oct', 'ABC12345678', 1, 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2);
insert into #tempsurvey values (2016,'Oct', 'DEF12345678', 1, 4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5);

with cte as (
  select t.[year], t.[month], t.customer_id, t.survey, x.question, x.answer
    from #tempsurvey t
      cross apply (values ('q1',q1) ,('q2',q2) ,('q3',q3) ,('q4',q4) ,('q5',q5) ,('q6',q6) ,('q7',q7) ,('q8',q8) ,('q9',q9) ,('q10',q10) ,('q11',q11) ,('q12',q12) ,('q13',q13) ,('q14',q14) ,('q15',q15) ,('q16',q16) ,('q17',q17) ,('q18',q18) ,('q19',q19) ,('q20',q20) ,('q21',q21) ,('q22',q22) ,('q23',q23) ,('q24',q24) ,('q25',q25) ,('q26',q26) ,('q27',q27) ,('q28',q28) ,('q29',q29)) 
      as x (Question,Answer)
 )
  select [year], [month], [survey], question, [1]=sum(case when answer=1 then 1 else 0 end), [2]=sum(case when answer=2 then 1 else 0 end), [3]=sum(case when answer=3 then 1 else 0 end), [4]=sum(case when answer=4 then 1 else 0 end), [5]=sum(case when answer=5 then 1 else 0 end)
    from cte
      group by [year], [month], [survey], question;

  drop table #tempsurvey;
```

Brad Schulz on cross apply: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/search/label/CROSS%20APPLY

Comment: Thanks! If you want to reorganize the table like Joe Enos suggested, you can use the inner part of the cte to generate that. Also, if your answers are nullable, and you want to handle that, switch to outer apply.

Comment: sounds good, now using the question column and survey column I can now pull back the question titles! Youre the best SqlZim!

Answer (score 1):

Sean is correct.
It will go like this:

```
with subquery as (
  select year, month, survey, question, tempVal from #table
  unpivot
  (tempVal for question in (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, ..., q29)) as up
)
select year, month, survey, question,
  sum(case when tempVal = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as a1,
  sum(case when tempVal = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as a2,
  sum(case when tempVal = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as a3,
  sum(case when tempVal = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as a4,
  sum(case when tempVal = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as a5
from subquery
group by year, month, survey, question
```

Comment: Thanks Nimdil, I was halfway through writing this when SqlZim performed the cross apply instead. Also correct too, many thanks